# HPSA (HP Server Automation)

Tags: oracle, automation, hp-server-automation

Using HP SA (HP Server Automation) version 9 for automation and its Oracle database consumes inordinately large amounts of CPU resources.  Anyone have a similar experience?

Comment: More info about sizing of your core/db (CPU,MEM. disk I/O) and how many servers you manage will help.

Answer (score 0):

As @[Fleole](https://serverfault.com/users/6827/fleole) commented, we need mroe information about what you are trying to do.

I've been working with HPSA for 8+ years now (since before HP bought Opsware), and Core/Mesh sizing has always been something along the lines of a black art, since you need to know at least the following:

- number of managed servers expected
- platform(s) to be managed
- typical workload(s) to be done

  - OS provisioning
  - patching / OS updates
  - software deployments
- frequency of workloads
- and more

If you are using the Oracle provided with HPSA, then you *likely* have an undersized server running the Model Repository.

If you're running a single box Core (ie Model Repository, Infrastructure, Slice, & OS Prov all on one server), then identifying *what* is causing "inordinately large amounts of CPU resources" to be consumed (and defining what you mean by "inordinately large") is a time for deeper analysis.